# Filter this string!

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to write a program that will filter out some characters in a string, so that the remaining spells out (part of) the other string.

Let's say we received the string "123456781234567812345678", and the second string is "314159".

First, we put a pointer on the second string:

```
314159
^
```

So the pointer is now on 3, and we replace the not-3 characters with a hashtag until the first 3:

```
##3456781234567812345678
```

We then move the pointer to the next character until we have iterated through the string.

## Specs

- You may use any character to replace "#", and the first string will not contain the hashtag (or the replaced hashtag).
- The second string will always be longer than enough.
- Both strings will only contain ASCII printable characters (U+0020-U+007F).

## Testcases

```
input1: 123456781234567812345678
input2: 314159
output: ##3#####1##4####1###5###

input1: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
input2: dilemma
output: ###d####i##l##############
```

Comment: @KennyLau could always have waited a minute to explain your question before posting it lmao

Comment: @KennyLau You're posting a lot of challenges, which is great, but I feel like you could do better taking more time to improve and clarify each one before posting it.

Comment: Could you edit to specify which approximations to pi are acceptable? Otherwise I can save a lot of bytes by using the traditional approximation 3.

Comment: Really, this whole use of pi seems gratuitous. The string to keep could be any string, or an input. Pi just means languages with it built in have it shorter.

Comment: @xnor Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Does "The second string will always be longer than enough." mean that it will always contain the first string as a subsequence?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77719/41019)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/is-string-x-a-subsequence-of-string-y).

Comment: You should probably add a testcase where `input1` contains all characters of `input 2` and more..

Answer (score 2):

## C#6, 112 bytes

```csharp
string c(string h,string n)=>h==""?"":h[0]==n[0]?h[0]+c(h.Substring(1),n.Substring(1)):"#"+c(h.Substring(1),n);
```

Recursive function, takes haystack h (input1) and needles n (input2).

- If Haystack is empty, return it.
- if first characters of haystack and needle are equal, keep the first character and call recursively while skipping the first char on both parameters
- else return the replacement character (fixed to # here) followed by a recursive call again skipping the first character from haystack only.

Major factor for the length is the long name of Substring, but it's not long enough (compared to the number of usages) that a wrapping function would help to reduce further.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 46 bytes

```js
a=>b=>a.replace(/./g,x=>x==b[i]?(i++,x):0,i=0)
```

Uses `0` as the replacement char.

Comment: I think you should be able to save 3 bytes by using `replace` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 69

```
def f(a,b,c=''):
 for x in a:y=x==b[0];c+=x*y or'#';b=b[y:]
 return c
```

Uses the hash for the replacement char, and take the original and replacement as a and b respectively.

Test case:

```
assert f('123456781234567812345678', '314159') == '##3#####1##4####1###5###'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 115 Bytes

```python
n,f=input()
for a in str(f):
 x,r=0,""
 for b in str(n):
  if x==0and b==a:c,x="#",1
  else:c=b
  r+=c
 n=r
print n
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 44 bytes

If someone helps me golf it down by any amount, then I can say crossed-out 44 is still 44

```
->s,r{s.gsub(/./){$&==r[0]?(r[0]='';$&):?#}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 77 bytes

```
sub _{$p=substr$f,0,1,''}($_,$f)=@ARGV;_;print map{$_ eq$p?_&&$_||$_:'#'}/./g
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 18 chars / 23 bytes

```
îⓢ⒨≔í⟨Ḁ?(Ḁ⧺,$):0)⨝
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B%22123456781234567812345678%22%2C%22314159%22%5D&code=%C3%AE%E2%93%A2%E2%92%A8%E2%89%94%C3%AD%E2%9F%A8%E1%B8%80%3F%28%E1%B8%80%E2%A7%BA%2C%24%29%3A%E2%8D%98%23%29%E2%A8%9D)</kbd>

Ayyy not bad. Uses 0 as the replacement char. It's just the same algorithm that I used in my JS answer.

Comment: Seems to work on Chrome for me.

Comment: Yeah, this answer was made back when Firefox was still the only browser with enough ES6 support for .

Answer (score 1):

I realize that there's already another JS-based solution posted using the `.replace` method that's shorter, but I'd like to submit my answers anyways...

### CoffeeScript, 55 bytes

Builds a string and returns it:

```coffee
f=(a,b,i=0,s='')->s+=c==b[i]&&b[i++]||'#'for j,c of a;s
```

### JavaScript, 53 bytes

Operates on an array of characters from the original string:

```js
f=(a,b,i=0)=>[...a].map(c=>c==b[i]?b[i++]:`#`).join``
```

Comment: You can drop the `f=` in both.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 81 bytes

```
A[99];char*b=A,*a=A+50;main(){gets(a),gets(b);while(*a)putchar(*a++^*b?35:*b++);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 56 bytes

```haskell
""%_="";(a:b)%l|a==head(l++"é")=a:b%(tail l)|0<1='#':b%l
```

Comment: You can pattern match the `head` and `tail` together with `@` for the whole list. I don't think you need `++"é"`, because of the 2nd spec: "The second string will always be longer than enough". `(a:b)%l@(c:d)|a==c=a:b%d|0<1='#':b%l`.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathcad, [tbd] bytes

[image]

---

Mathcad byte equivalence to be determined.   Note that the programming operators "while", "break" and "on error" only require 1 key-combination to enter (ctl-], ctl-{ and ctl-', respectively) - they cannot be typed verbatim.  What you see in the image is exactly what gets entered onto the Mathcad worksheet and the results are live - change a or b, or the function arguments, and the results update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 136 bytes

```java
void i(int[]a,int[]b){int i=0,j=0,n=a.length;for(;i<b.length;i++)for(;j<n;j++)if(a[j]==b[i]){j++;break;}else a[j]=0;for(;j<n;)a[j++]=0;}
```

#### Ungolfed

```java
void i(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = a.length;
    for (; i < b.length; i++)
        for (; j < n; j++)
            if (a[j] == b[i]) {
                j++;
                break;
            } else a[j] = 0;
    for (; j < n; ) a[j++] = 0;
}
```

#### Notes

- Uses the `NUL` character as replacement, any of the first 10 would do. If you wanted a visible replacement character, this would be one byte longer.
- Input are two integer arrays of charcodes. `int[]` is one byte shorter than `char[]`.

#### Outputs

```
Input 1:    123456781234567812345678
Input 2:    314159
Output:       3     1  4    1   5   
Input 1:    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Input 2:    dilemma
Output:        d    i  l              
Input 1:    314asd159asdasd
Input 2:    314159
Output:     314   159
```

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 72 bytes

```
param($a,$b)$i=0;-join([char[]]$a|%{if($_-ceq$b[$i]){$_;$i++}else{'#'}})
```

Takes input `$a` and `$b`, sets `$i` to `0` (our pointer). Then, we cast `$a` as a char-array and pump it through a loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we check if the current character is case-sensitive-equal to the character in `$b` under the pointer. If it is, add it to the pipeline with `$_` and increment our counter. Otherwise, add a `'#'` to the pipeline. All of those characters are then gathered up `(...)` and `-join`ed into one string, which is then re-placed onto the pipeline. Output is implicit.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\filter-this-string.ps1 "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" "PPCG"
P###########P#########C####G###
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP(271)

This is my first php code so it is stronly likely that it can be golfed more

```
    function g($s,$b){$r='';foreach(str_split(strrev($b))as $i) $r='([^'.$i.']*?)(?:([^'.$i.']$)|'.$i.$r.')';$line=preg_replace_callback('/'.$r.'/',function ($m) {$a='';for($i=1;$i<count($m);$i=$i+2)$a=$a.$m[$i].$m[$i+1].'#';return $a;},$s);echo substr($line,0,strlen($s));}
```

- I used non-recursive regex where I am certain that a recursive breakthrough is available.
- Test it

  ```
  <?php
  g("uuuuaaaaavabbbbccccd","abcd");
  function g($s,$b){$r='';foreach(str_split(strrev($b))as $i) $r='([^'.$i.']*?)(?:([^'.$i.']$)|'.$i.$r.')';$line=preg_replace_callback('/'.$r.'/',function ($m) {$a='';for($i=1;$i<count($m);$i=$i+2)$a=$a.$m[$i].$m[$i+1].'#';return $a;},$s);echo substr($line,0,strlen($s));}
  ```

  - In/Outputs

    ```
     uuuuaaaaavabbbbccccd
     abcd

     uuuu#aaaava#bbb#ccc#
    ```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
.o²g£
```

Explanation:

```
.o     # Overlap function.
         12345 and 1456 yields:
         1  456
  ²    # Get the second input.
   g   # Take the length.
    £  # Take the substring [0:length] and implicitly output.
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Lm_CsmfCow&input=MzE0MTU5CjEyMzQ1Njc4MTIzNDU2NzgxMjM0NTY3OA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 197 bytes

I was determined to solve this with regex, and I did. I did not really think it would be short.

```
def f(n,h):r=re.match(("([^{}]*)(.)"*len(n)).format(*n),h).groups();return"".join([i if i in n else"#"for i in"".join(["".join(d)for d in zip(["#"*len(i)for i in r[::2]],r[::-1][::2][::-1])])])
```

Ungolfed:

```
def fs(needle, haystack):
    rx = "([^{}]*)(.)"
    rx *= len(needle)
    rx = rx.format(*needle)
    r  = re.match(rx, haystack).groups()
    nd = r[::-1][::2][::-1]
    hs = r[::2]
    hs = ["#" * len(i) for i in hs]
    nh = "".join([i if i in needle else "#" for i in "".join(["".join(d) for d in zip(hs, nd)])])
    return nh
```

I wanted to do it with regex so I can do it again in Factor which, as a point-free functional language, does not do explicit looping. Haskell also does not do explicit looping and the Haskell solution does not use pattern matching but I don't understand the Haskell solution.

[Here's what I used to come up with the regex](https://regex101.com/r/fL2fT5/1).

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5, 67

```
def f(a,b):b=[*b];return"".join(y==b[0]and b.pop(0)or"#"for y in a)
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(a, b):
    b = [*b] #Convert string to list; yeah Python 3.5
    c = []
    for y in a:
       if y==b[0]:
          c.append(b.pop(0))
       else:
          c.append("#")
    return "".join(c)
```

Try it [here](https://repl.it/CO1y/2)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 65 bytes

```php
function f($s,$t){for(;a&$c=$s[$i++];)echo$c==$t[$k]?$t[$k++]:_;}
```

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 97 bytes

```
arg a b
o=
do while b>''
  parse var b n+1 b
  parse var a p (n)h+1 a
  o=o||translate(p,,p)h
  end
say o
```

As usual, readability is severely hampered by skipping every possible whitespace and abuttal operator.