# Substring Substitution

Tags: code-golf, string, substitution

### Challenge

Implement a program that given three strings `a`, `b`, and `c`, substitutes all instances of the substring `b` in `a` with `c`.

In other words, implement Ruby's `String#gsub` with strings instead of regexes (`a.gsub b, c`).

### Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- You may not use a builtin that performs this exact task.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins.

### Dupe alert

Not a duplicate of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77719/subsequence-substitution).

### Test case

```
sub("test 1 test 1 test 1", "1", "what")
  --> "test what test what test what"
```

Comment: This has all the typical problems of *do X without Y* challenges. Are splitting/joining built-ins allowed? If so, this is trivial and there's really no reason to ban sibstitution built-ins. If not, what *is* allowed?

Comment: @wat You answered yes for Dennis's question about using string split/join, then said in question that they are not allowed. So they are allowed and not allowed at the same time?

Comment: By "join or split strings" do you mean "join or split anything"? As an example Jelly 5 bytes `œṣµj⁵` does not split any strings since Jelly has no strings.

Comment: Modifying the challenge to fit Jelly will just result in another language being pointed out that doesn't fit the wording. It's easiest just not to ban built ins.

Comment: @wat - lists, numbers (decimals, reals, complex) and characters. The above is achieved with a list of characters.

Comment: If everyone who voted negatively can retract their downvote, the challenge will be seen by more people.

Comment: Fair enough. Despite the task's simplicity, a few test cases would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œṣj⁵
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZPhuaNq4oG1&input=&args=ImNsYXNzaWMgYXNzYXNzaW5hdGlvbiI+ImFzcyI+ImJ1dHQi)

#### How it works

```
œṣj⁵  Main link. Arguments: x, y, z (strings)

œṣ    Split x around occurrences of y.
  j⁵  Join the resulting string array with separator z.
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
(a,b,c)=>a.split(b).join(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
(.splitOn).(.).intercalate
```

Argument order is `c` `b` `a`. Usage example: `( (.splitOn).(.).intercalate )  "ww" "ee" "aeedwwfeegeh"` -> `"awwdwwfwwgeh"`.

Just some library functions to split the input string at every `b` and rejoin the parts with `c` in-between.